Solving recurrence relation $N^\epsilon_{n+1} = 2x N^\epsilon_n - (1 - i (t_n + \epsilon)) (1 + i (t_{n-1} + \epsilon)) N^\epsilon_{n-1}$,
I’m working on evaluating a recursive relation that comes up in the context of fixed-point Grover search (reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3305).
Problem:
The recursive relation is given by:
$N^\epsilon_{n+1} = 2x N^\epsilon_n - (1 - i (t_n + \epsilon)) (1 + i (t_{n-1} + \epsilon)) N^\epsilon_{n-1}$,
where
$t_n = w \tan\left(\frac{n \pi}{L}\right)$.
Here, $w$ is a constant. For the special case $\epsilon = 0$, I know that $N^0_L = \gamma^L T_L(x / \gamma)$. $T_L$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind. (For a proof, see Section 4.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2403.02057)
For $\epsilon=0$, the recursive relation is equivalent to:
$N^\epsilon_{n+1} = 2x N^\epsilon_n - (1 - w) (1 + w) N^\epsilon_{n-1}$.
Goal:
I’m trying to find an analytical expression that approximates the behavior of $N_n^\epsilon$ for large and odd $L$ and small $\epsilon$ ($N^{\epsilon}_L = N^{(0)}_L + \epsilon N^{(1)}_L + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$). Ideally, I want an approximation of $N^{(1)}_L$ for large $L$.
If it is not possible to get such an analytical estimate, is there any statement on how this recursive relation behaves for small $\epsilon$ and large $L$, without implementing it numerically?
Attempts so far:
I’ve tried to expand the recursion explicitly, leading me to the following form:
$N_L^{w, \epsilon} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=0}^{(L-1)/2} (2x)^{2j} \sum_{k_1=2}^{2j+2} (\tilde{t}_{k_1} + \tilde{t}_2) \sum_{k_2=k_1+2}^{2j+4} \tilde{t}_{k_2} \dots \sum_{k_{4-j} = k_{4-j-1} + 2}^{L} \tilde{t}_{k_{4-j}}$,
where $\tilde{t}_n = -(1 - i (t_n + \epsilon)) (1 + i (t_{n-1} + \epsilon))$.
I tried to plot individual terms in the sum over $j$ to see if any could be neglected, but I haven’t identified any clear simplifications yet.

To start playing, I looked at a perturbation of the standard Chebyshev recurrence relation, namely
$$ \begin{aligned} t_0(x)&=1 
\\ t_1(x)&=x 
\\ t_k(x)&= 2 x t_{k-1}(x) -(1+\epsilon)\,  t_{k-2}(x) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)\end{aligned}$$
Using Mathematica,
ClearAll["Global`*"];
t[0]=1; t[1]=x; t[k_] := t[k] = Expand[ 2 x t[k-1] - (1+eps) t[k-2] ];
s[k_] := Normal[Series[t[k], {eps,0,1}]]
n[0]=0;nn[1]=0;nn[2]=-1; nn[k_]:=Expand[2x k/(k-1) n[k-1]-(k/(k-2))n[k-2]];
Table[{k,s[k],n[k]=( s[k]-ChebyshevT[k,x] )/eps,nn[k]}, {k,1,11}]//MatrixForm

I found the solution $t_k(x)=T_k(x)+\epsilon N_k(x)$, where $T_k(x)$ are the standard Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind and $N_k(x)$ satisfies
$$
\begin{aligned} N_1(x)&=0 
\\ N_2(x)&=-1 
\\ N_k(x)/k&= 2 x N_{k-1}(x)/(k-1) - N_{k-2}(x)/(k-2)
\end{aligned}
$$
Put differently, the function $M_k(x)=N_k(x)/k$ satisfies
$$
\begin{aligned} M_1(x)&=0 
\\ M_2(x)&=-1/2 
\\ M_k(x)&= 2 x M_{k-1}(x) - M_{k-2}(x)
\end{aligned}
$$
the standard Chebyshev recurrence with modified starting values. It can be extended to $M_0(x)=1/2$ and is solved by $M_n(x)=-1/2\, U_{n-2}(x)$, where $U_n(x)$ are the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind.
Thus, $N_k(x) = -k/2 \, U_{k-2}(x)$.
A similar approach may work for you starting with the distorted recurrence and an additional factor to the $\epsilon$.
However, I am not sure what type of analytical solution you are looking for in the large $k$ limit. The Chebyshev polnyomials are polynomials with linearly increasing degree and all roots in the interval [−1,1].
There is no limiting function. Also, with the additional factor of $k$ that is picked up on top of the Chebyshev polynomial, your functions' maximal value on the interval is expected to grow linearly with $k$ and may not support the perturbation approach.
Of course, you could be looking for a limiting distribution of roots for large $k$ on the interval...
